# Sqoop import from couchbase to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, couchbase, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

On Ubuntu, using couchbase 2.5.1, cloudera cdh4, the hadoop plugin for couchbase and oracle jdk 6. Everything installs fine (seemingly), I can work with hadoop and couchbase independently with no problems, but when I try use the plugin as follows

```
sqoop import --connect http://127.0.0.1:8091/ --table DUMP
```

I get the following errors

```
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
14/04/11 11:44:08 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.6.0
14/04/11 11:44:08 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/04/11 11:44:08 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-vagrant/compile/30e6774902d338663db059706cde5b12/DUMP.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/04/11 11:44:09 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-vagrant/compile/30e6774902d338663db059706cde5b12/DUMP.jar
14/04/11 11:44:09 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of DUMP
14/04/11 11:44:09 WARN util.Jars: No such class couchbase doesn't use a jdbc driver available.
14/04/11 11:44:11 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/04/11 11:44:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/04/11 11:44:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8021. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Or what I can do to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the syntax I was using was wrong. Assuming we want to import the `beer-sample` bucket from couchbase into HDFS, the correct syntax is below, where the bucket name is actually passed as the `username`.

```
sqoop import --connect http://localhost:8091/pools --password password --username beer-sample --table DUMP
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you will be able to connect to a couchbase bucket with password using couchbase hadoop plugin. I used to get authentication exception and was never able to solve it. I edited the source code and then I was able to get it working.